# Find and count coincidences in mongo array based on a condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine that I have a collection of documents similar to :

```
{
_id :ObjectId("45645645gdfgdfgdf"),
article:"article one",
topic:["config","develop","show"],
keys[
    {subject:"one",object"abc"},
    {subject:"one",object"def"},
    {subject:"two",object"ghi"},
    {subject:"four",object"jkl"},
    {subject:"four",object"mnl"},
    {subject:"four",object"mnl"},
]
},
{
_id :ObjectId("45645645gdfgdfgdf"),
article:"article two",
topic:["config","installing"],
keys[
    {subject:"one",object"abc"},
    {subject:"one",object"def"},
    {subject:"two",object"ghi"},
    {subject:"two",object"jkl"},
]
},
{
_id :ObjectId("45645645gdfgdfgdf"),
article:"article three",
topic:["config","installing"],
keys[
    {subject:"five",object"abc"},
    {subject:"five",object"def"},
    {subject:"two",object"ghi"},
    {subject:"two",object"jkl"},
]
}
```

I want to count every subject in the array based on a condition, filtered by the topic, for example, imagine that I search by topic : "config" and subject: ["one","four"] the result need to be

```
{article :"article one", sum:5},{article :"article two", sum:2}
```

thks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"topic":"config","subject":{"$in":["one","four"]}}},
  {"$project":{
    "article":1,
    "sum":{
      "$size":{
        "$filter":{
          "input":"$keys",
          "cond":{"$in":["$$this.subject",["one","four"]]}
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, this code help me to understands the query idea of mongo